# Why I lost the value of my global variable? FIXED

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to save the text selected by the user in a variable in my chrome extension. For this, I use `document.getSelection()` method.

I have the global variable "theText". When I select some text, in the first and second log I have the text I selected. That's ok. But in the third log, I lost the value of my variable. Why? I read a lot about the scope in JavaScript, but I think my variable is global, so I don't understand why I lost my value.

The "definitionPopup" is an id of my toolbar in HTML.

Can you help me? I'm noobie here.

Thanks!

This is my js file:

```
var theText;
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    var text = getSelectionText()
    console.log(text.length);
    if (text.length > 0){ // check there's some text selected
        theText = text;
        console.log("Second log theText " + theText);
    }
}, false);

function getSelectionText(){
    var selectedText = "";
    if (document.getSelection()){
        selectedText = document.getSelection().toString();
        if(selectedText.length > 0){
            theText = selectedText;
            console.log("First test theText " + theText);
        }
    }
    return selectedText;
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  //Call deninion service
  $("#definitionPopup").click(function(e){
    console.log('Third test theText '+ theText);
    ...
  });
```

my toolbar.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/option-selected.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="toolbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li id="searchTextPopup"><input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Buscar..."></li>
        <li id="definitionPopup"><a href="#">Definiciones</a></li>
        <li id="synonymPopup"><a href="#">Palabras parecidas</a></li>
        <li id="antonymPopup"><a href="#">Palabras distintas</a></li>
        <li id="imgPopup"><a href="#">Pictogramas</a></li>
        <li id="youtubePopup" ><a href="#" >Youtube</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

add-toolbar.js I create my iframe

```
var height = '60px';
//var iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); //the "error" is here.
//I create div instead of iframe
var iframe = document.body.createElement('div');
iframe.setAttribute("id", "customToolbarMenu");

//iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL('../toolbar.html'); //change this
//for this
$("#customToolbarMenu").load(chrome.extension.getURL('../toolbar.html')); 

document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);


var bodyStyle = document.body.style;
var cssTransform = 'transform' in bodyStyle ? 'transform' : 'webkitTransform';
bodyStyle[cssTransform] = 'translateY(' + height + ')';
```

Comment: My best guess is that there's some sort of accidental IIFE or other similar effect which is causing the function containing the third console log to use the value of theText from when the function is created rather than when it's run (and thus being empty), but as you omitted most of the code around it, that's hard to say for certain.

Comment: Could you post your complete code? I just tested a slightly modified version of your code for testing purposes and the variable 'Thetext' was holding it's expected value in the 'third test'.

Comment: Are the logs actually occurring in the expected order? It's a bit weird that you install the one listeners on the `window` using the native DOM API, and the other on a particular element using jQuery.

Comment: I posted more code for the application. I hope that helps. I have also modified the order of the logs, I had misplaced the first and the second. Jorge, what modidified? I don't understand what's wrong in my code :( Thanks you all!

Comment: "add-toolbar.js" what doing actually? I can see the it is adding iframe, every iframe have own scope, DOM tree and new window. So I think "var theText;" out of scope. You may say like that then why you getting first and second console because of when you typing "theText = selectedText;" that means if "theText" no available then JS create new variable in window object. I just wrote my thought otherwise it should work.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The problem is the iframe. I have changed my code creating a "div" instead of "iframe" and it works! I'll change the code in this post. Thanks guys! ^^